# .htaccess Rewrite Rule to keep exception for folders

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I used this code

```
RewriteRule ^/([^\.]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It worked fine for me but when i tried to visit a file in next folder like `http://example.com/blog` it automatically shows the profile.php code. Is there any method to skip folders during that htaccess?

PS: In username Alphanumeric characters, hyphen(-), dot(.) and underscore(_) are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In username Alphanumeric characters, hyphen(-), dot(.) and underscore(_) are allowed.

Restrict your pattern to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([\w.-]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: and what about the username has dot(.) its not working for usernames having dot(.) in it.

Comment: and also not working if I tried to visit this  `example.com/blog/?p=1`